# Attach document to SharePoint 2010 List item with JSOM & WCF Service

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, jsom, wcf, jquery-ajax

I've to attach the document to list item with JSOM & WCF Service.

Please check the below code

```
function createListItem(webUrl, listName, itemProperties, success, failure) {

    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data.responseJSON.error);
        }
    });
}
```

I've used below code snippet to save multiple values in lookup column,

```
var listItems = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < Id.length; i++) {
            var __metadata = {
                __metadata: { uri: "http://test site/sites/Site1/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/List Name(" + Id[i] + ")" }
            }            
            listItems.push(__metadata);
        }




    var itemProperties = {
        'Title': title,            
        'Desciption': Desc,
        'Column Name': listItems // Multiple Values
    };
```

My Question is how can I add attachment here? Also I want to add the Multiple values to single lookup column like (tst1, test2, test3, test4) from the multi-Select Check-Box list.